# 3SUM to a specific value

Tags: python, algorithm, subset-sum

I currently have a solution, but still about 300% too slow. The problem is to find a subset of three numbers with a sum n from a given list.

```
goal = int(input().split()[1]) #The desired sum
numbers = list(map(int, input().split())) #User-inputted numbers

myDict = {} #Created so we can quickly check if a number is present in the list

for i in numbers: #The amount of each number is stored in the dict, eg. 439797: 2
    if i in myDict:
        myDict[i] += 1
    else:
        myDict[i] = 1


numbers = sorted(numbers)


for start in range(0, len(numbers)):
    for end in range(1, len(numbers)):
        myDict[numbers[start]] -= 1 
        myDict[numbers[end]] -= 1 
        #This is done so that the same number isn't used twice
        if goal-numbers[start]-numbers[end] in myDict:
            if myDict[goal-numbers[start]-numbers[end]] > 0:
                print(goal-numbers[start]-numbers[end], numbers[start], numbers[end])
                quit()
        myDict[numbers[start]] += 1
        myDict[numbers[end]] += 1
```

Comment: If you're going through the sorting road, you can use binary search to speed up the search for the third number. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Comment: @ChatterOne Thanks, but what do you mean, exactly? How is that faster than checking the dictionary right away? I don't quite get it.

Comment: You can find the same problem here: https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/7380/Concise-O(N2)-Java-solution a lot of solutions and disucussion on the subject including optimisations

Comment: Actually, that isn't exactly the same problem. And you are right - I could find a lot of ready information, but I'd like to know how to speed up _my solution_.

Comment: Are numbers integer? What is range of n?

Comment: List size < 5000, n and all the other integers -10^9 up to 10^9

Comment: You may only use a number once. If a number appears many times, you may use like you described to form 5.

Comment: @Kurns end should start at start, not 1. Also there is no benefit to sorting the numbers in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully agree with shinobi, but if you need to calculate these kind of tasks quickly, C++ is the way to go. The code would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0, i < len(numbers); i++) {
    int m = numbers[i];
    for (int j = i + 1, j < len(numbers); j++) {
        int n = numbers[j];
        if (n != m) {
            int k = goal - m - n;
            if (k != m && k != n && myDict[k]) {
                doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're indexing your dictionary six times in the inner loop, which is completely unnecessary, and probably accounts for the bulk of your running time.  You can do with just a single indexing op, and without any modifications to the dictionary:

```
for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
    m = numbers[i]
    for j in range(i + 1, len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[j]
        if n != m:
            k = goal - m - n
            if k != m and k != n and k in myDict:
                # accept triple (m, n, k)
```

Also, as already suggested in the comments, there's no point in sorting the input.

*Update*:  Also from the comments, your inner loop starts at 1.  This approximately doubles your running time.

*Update 2*: Also, given that the count from the dictionary is no longer needed, the dictionary can be a set now (not sure if it's going to affect performance in any meaningful way though.)

*Update 3*: Added check for `n != m`.

Comment: There is one issue: what if there are two of the same numbers in the input? Then surely k=m or k=n?

Comment: @Kurns: No, the `k != m and k != n` check makes sure that this doesn't happen.  I forgot to check `n != m`, though, which I've fixed now.